# How to reference constructor this in another function

Tags: javascript, d3.js, constructor, es6-class

How can I convert the following portion to be converted to one written with JS Class.

**`svg authored with d3 without JS Class`**

```js
const svgns = 'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg';
const width = 1280;
const height = 600;

const main = d3.select('div')
    .style('position', 'relative')
    .append('svg')
    .attr('xmlns', svgns)
    .attr('viewBox', `0 0 ${width} ${height}`)
    .attr('id', 'svg');

//listener
const listener = main
    .append('rect')
    .attr('class', 'vBoxRect')
    .attr('width', `${width}`)
    .attr('height', `${height}`)
    .attr('fill', 'none')
    .attr('stroke', 'red')
    .style("pointer-events", "all");

const focusText = main
    .append('g')
    .attr('class', 'someTxt')
    .append('text')
    .attr("opacity", '0')
    .attr('x', '100')
    .attr('y', '100')
    .html('I am a test text');


listener
    .on('mouseover', function() {
        focusText.attr("opacity", 1);
    })
    .on('mouseout', function() {
        focusText.attr("opacity", 0);
    })
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://d3js.org/d3.v7.min.js"></script>
<body>
    <div id="viz"></div>
</body>
<script src="min.js">
</script>

</html>
```

**`svg authored with d3 + JS Class and Constructor`**

```js
const svgns = 'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg';
const width = 1280;
const height = 600;

class Base {
    constructor(svgns, width, height) {
        this.base = d3.select('div')
            .style('position', 'relative')
            .append('svg')
            .attr('xmlns', svgns)
            .attr('viewBox', `0 0 ${width} ${height}`)
            .attr('id', 'svg');

        //listener
        this.listener = this.base
            .append('rect')
            .attr('class', 'vBoxRect')
            .attr('width', `${width}`)
            .attr('height', `${height}`)
            .attr('fill', 'none')
            .attr('stroke', 'red')
            .style("pointer-events", "all");

        this.focusText = this.base
            .append('g')
            .attr('class', 'someTxt')
            .append('text')
            .attr("opacity", '0')
            .attr('x', '100')
            .attr('y', '100')
            .html('I am a test text');


        this.listener
            .on('mouseover', function() {
                this.focusText.attr("opacity", 1);
            })
            .on('mouseout', function() {
                this.focusText.attr("opacity", 0);
            })
    }

};
const svg = new Base(svgns, width, height);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://d3js.org/d3.v7.min.js"></script>
<body>
    <div id="viz"></div>
</body>
<script src="min.js">
</script>

</html>
```

The code is currently failing here

```
//without class 
listener
    .on('mouseover', function() {
        focusText.attr("opacity", 1);
    })
    .on('mouseout', function() {
        focusText.attr("opacity", 0);
    })

//with Class 
this.listener
    .on('mouseover', function() {
        this.focusText.attr("opacity", 1);
    })
    .on('mouseout', function() {
        this.focusText.attr("opacity", 0);
    })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that the event system sets its own value of `this` when it calls your listener callback.  In DOM events, the value of `this` is typically the DOM element that triggered the event.  There are a couple of ways to override that value of `this` and specify your own.

To use the lexical value of `this`, then use an arrow function instead of a regular function:

```
this.listener
    .on('mouseover', () => {
        this.focusText.attr("opacity", 1);
    })
    .on('mouseout', () => {
        this.focusText.attr("opacity", 0);
    })
```

Arrow functions ignore the value of `this` that comes from how the function is called and they use the lexical value of `this` which is the value of `this` in the execution environment when the function is defined - which is what you want in your context.

---

Or, you can also use `.bind()` (which creates a little stub functions that re-establishes the value of `this` you want):

```
this.listener
    .on('mouseover', function() {
        this.focusText.attr("opacity", 1);
    }.bind(this))
    .on('mouseout', function() {
        this.focusText.attr("opacity", 0);
    }.bind(this))
```